# How to get the last n bytes of a bytes32 in assembly?

Tags: bytes, assembly

I have the following code:

```
function getBytes5() public returns (bytes5) {
    uint256 x = now;        
    bytes memory inBytes = new bytes(32);
    bytes5 outBytes5;
    assembly {
         mstore(add(inBytes, 32), x)
         outBytes5 := mload(add(add(inBytes, 27), 5))
    }
    return outBytes5;
}
```

Which firstly stores the blockchain timestamp `now` in the `inBytes` variable and then tries to convert it from `bytes32` to `bytes5`. However, the result I get is:

```
{
    "0": "bytes5": 0x0000000000
}
```

My understanding is that `mload` loads the values at the given addresses and `add(add(inBytes, 27), 5)` will return the last 5 bytes of the `inBytes` variable. But maybe there's a flaw somewhere in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the location you're passing to `mload`. The memory addressing of `inBytes` is 32 bytes for the length, then the rest is the data. Since you're storing a uint256 at the 32 bytes after the length, the memory map is going to look something like this:

```
0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20
0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00 00 00 00 5C 6E 24 39
```

When you call `mload`, you pass in `add(add(inBytes, 27), 5)`, which is just inBytes+32, which loads the entire last 2 lines of the above hex. However, the way casting works, it takes the most significant bytes. Which is why `outBytes5` ends up all 0's. It's loading this portion to the variable:

0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20

0x**00 00 00 00 00** 00 00 00

0x00 00 00 00 5C 6E 24 39

To fix this, just change the `mload` location so the 5 bytes are the most significant bytes. This should work:

```
outBytes5 := mload(add(add(inBytes, 32), 27))
```

That should load 0x005C6E2439 to `outBytes5` in the above example.